# How to increase the performance of a scrollable listview which consists a non-scrollable gridview?

Tags: android, listview, gridview, scrollable

I have a listview where each item is showing a month calendar. In each item I have a gridview to show the date. So, by scrolling the list item I can see the calendar month is changing. But scrolling of listview is not smooth. By searching for the solution I have got so far that there are 5*7 =35 items in gridview rendering which makes the scrolling slow. So, I change the getItem() of Grid Adapter by returning only a text view instead of my layout.

I also used a AsyncTask to load the data which is then fed to the grid adapter. But still the scrolling is slow. If there is any alternating solution instead of creating 35 (each view for single date) views with loop, kindly let me know.

Here is the image for understanding the problem. We can scroll in both side:

[image]

There are lots of code regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Use viewTypes (override [getItemViewType(int pos)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) and [getViewTypeCount()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount())) in yout adapter. One view type will be title(e.q. textView NOVEMBER 2016), second type will be header (probably LinearLayout with textViews - SUN MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT) and third type will be LinearLayout with TextViews containing days.

Another way could be to recycle views inside of your calendar (the GrideView would keep the views infalted and you would only change its visibility and text)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  1st solution : i'm confused as i tested inflating only a TextView. 2nd solution : i don't understand! Can you please describe briefly?

Comment: here is the code of getItem() :                                                                @Override
    public View getView(int i, View itemView, final ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if(itemView==null){                                                                                      itemView= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.test_view,null);}
}
        return itemView;
    }

Comment: What kind of adapter are you using?

Comment: I am extending BaseAdapter for Grid Adapter